# Uncaught #<Object> SQLitePlugin for Cordova

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

I am having troubles making to run my Cordova proyect after update my Cordova-Android version.

I updated the proyect from 'Cordova-android' 3.6.4 to 'Cordova-android' 5.2.2

Then i did a new fresh proyect, with android platform and i installed all the plugins that i need.

The app works in a 4.4.2 Android Tablet. But when i update the system from my tablet to 5.1.1 (lollypop) i have a big problem with SQLiteplugin.

I have this error:

```
Uncaught #<Object> plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:336
```

This is the exception

```
'InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: This transaction is already finalized. Transactions are committed after its success or failure handlers are called. If you are using a Promise to handle callbacks, be aware that implementations following the A+ standard adhere to run-to-completion semantics and so Promise resolution occurs on a subsequent tick and therefore after the transaction commits.',
        code: 11
```

I installed via npm the SQLitePlugin with:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
```

The app don't run, only black screen. I have no idea what to do.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Did you try to check if the app starts when the plugin sqlite is removed (or other plugin you might use in your project)?

Comment: The application worked correctly on android 4.4.2 operating system. But it does not on 5.1.1.

I guess some plugin is causing problems. Apparently I have updated to the latest versions.

If I remove the plugin SQLite can not start the application because it makes access to the database.

I tried reinstalling the plugin and twice with the same result.

Comment: When your project is built with cordova-android 3.6.4 (which was working ok on android 4.4.2 if I understood you correctly), does it run on android 5.1.1 (it should from my experience)?